# Fancybox 3 Transition Animation Effect Between IFrame Content

Tags: fancybox-3

I have a form that pulls up in a Fancybox 3 iframe. The user submits the form, it processes and forwards to a confirmation page. When this transition happens, Fancybox updates the iframe size of the confirmation page to the size of the content (which is smaller than the form). So far, so good.

However, I'd like to make this transition animated so the iframe doesn't just change the size, rather animates it smoothly as it transitions from larger to smaller. I see how to do this with inline content in the FancyBox3 documentation, but have yet to find how to make this happen with iframe content. Is it possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is currently not possible out of the box, if you are using auto-size feature. Maybe you could use `afterLoad` callback to store initial width/height values, then on next load event you could read new values and animate iframe wrapping element to the new values. It could work, but I have not tried that.